# why does the compiler doesn't give copiler error for below code?

Tags: java

I have just executed the below piece of code,

```
char a=5;
System.out.println(a);
```

The print statement prints nothing but a square box when executed in eclipse.
It could have given the compiler error right? because the above code doesn't make any sense.. Please correct me if am wrong..

Comment: it will print ASCII value of 5. It make sense.

Comment: The char is defined without the quotes   char a=5;

Comment: Try this link : [ASCII values](http://ascii.cl/?wb48617274=5D681385)

Comment: A lovely 8 identical answer question.

Answer (score 5):

The `char` type in Java has two meanings, sort of.  It's an integer type (a `char` can have values from 0 to 65535), but its intent is to represent Unicode characters (at least those in the basic multilingual plane).  If you print it out with `System.out.println`, the program will print the *character* represented by the integer, not the integer itself.

Since it's an integer type, though, you can assign an integer to it.  For example, since the character `'A'` is represented by the integer 65 in Unicode, the statements `c = 65;` and `c = 'A';` are totally equivalent.

So there's nothing illegal about the program.  But character 5 in Unicode (and previously in ASCII) is a "control character" that doesn't show up as anything when you print it.

Comment: `char` isn't limited to the Unicode BMP; It can contain a UTF-16 [surrogate](http://www.unicode.org/glossary/#surrogate_pair), which are used in pairs to represent a Unicode codepoint. Therefore, you can't say it represents a character without knowing that it's not a surrogate.

Comment: Yeah, and I also left out the fact that 65534 and 65535 don't represent Unicode characters.  Of course these details aren't of any interest to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The code makes sense.

You are creating a character with the Unicode codepoint 5 (same as [ASCII code 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enquiry_character)), which is a non-printable character.

It may make sense to do this in other circumstances (not printing it), and it certainly makes sense with printable characters.

If you wanted to print the digit "five", you could do

```
char a = '5'; // using a character literal
char b = 53;  // using an integer literal (for the code point)
```

Answer (score 1):

> A `char` is an unsigned integer in the range 0 to 65535 (I think; it's 0xffff) which prints out as the Unicode character corresponding to that number, assuming your computer supports Unicode. The values 0 to 127 (0x7f) correspond to Unicode's original precursor (ASCII) and 0 to 255 (0xff) is extended ASCII.

`char` values already are integers. You can do arithmetic with them.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning character code 5 to variable `a`. Take a look at this [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com). ASCII 5 is unprintable, if you change this value to 35 for example, it will print out a `#`. In this way, Java (and other languages) allow you to perform algorithms on character values.

```
    char a = 35;
    while (a < 100) {
        System.out.println(a);
        a++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

println prints a value or object. Printing single character is support - see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(char) , so no reason for compiler error.

It prints characters with ASCII value 5 which doesn't have any representation in your font so you see the square box.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a integer value to char data type and it will print random symbol as compiler not able to get the value of char "a" value.

Answer (score 0):

`char a=5;` is completely valid.  In Java a character is not simply a single letter, it can also be a numeric representation of an ASCII character. 5 is an "enquiry" character. If you set `char a = 126` you'll get a tilde character.

Answer (score 0):

There's no error in this code. You can assign a int value to a char variable. If you can make a for loop with assigning some int values you can see the some other chars also instead of boxes.